# Why Cannot find 'newArray' in scope when using return outside of if statement

Tags: swift, if-statement, return

```
import Foundation

func aVeryBigSum(ar: [Int]) -> Int {

    if ar[0] < ar[1]{
    
        var newArray = 1
        
    } else if ar[0] > ar[1[]{
        var newArray = 0
    }
    
    return newArray
}


print(aVeryBigSum(ar: [5,8]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating different `newArray`s in `if` and `else` statements. And you cannot use a property outside of its scope. So just return a value in `if` or `else` statement. Or create `newArray` in functions scope (not if-else statement's scope) like the second example.

---

**First**

```swift
func aVeryBigSum(ar: [Int]) -> Int {

  if ar[0] < ar[1] {
    return 1
  } else {
    return 0
  }
}
```

---

**Second**

```swift
func aVeryBigSum(ar: [Int]) -> Int {
  let newArray: Int

  if ar[0] < ar[1] {
    newArray = 1
  } else {
    newArray = 0
  }
  return newArray
}
```

[Scope & Context Explained In Swift](https://learnappmaking.com/scope-context-swift-how-to/#:%7E:text=The%20concept%20of%20scope%20states,challenging%20to%20grasp%20at%20first.)

Comment: If I do that I receive an error "Missing return in a function expected to return 'Int'

Comment: you are right please check my updated answer. @BabyProgrammer could you please mark as an accepted for others benefits?

Comment: Thank you emrcftci, I just hit the green tick. I am currently reading through the Scope & context link you provided. So glad for your help man, I have been stuck with this for hours.